# getting runtime version information of Qt5 library

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Is there inside the [Qt5](https://qt.io/) libraries (for Linux) a C++ function or an API to retrieve at runtime the precise version information of the Qt shared library?

The [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) has `gnu_get_libc_version`. The [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) has `curl_version`.

I want the equivalent for Qt5 (for the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project, if that matters). It uses a Qt5 X11 GUI interface.

Comment: [This page](https://linux.m2osw.com/find-qt-version-command-line-compile-time-run-time) mentions [`qVersion`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qVersion).

Comment: [QLibraryInfo::version()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibraryinfo.html#version)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted `qVersion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qVersion` or `QT_VERSION` (alternative).

To check a specific version: `QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)`.

Comment: QT_VERSION is a compile-time construct, not runtime